# Using pyautogui, how can I get Python to press Ctrl + F to find a word on a webpage? Prefer not to use Selenium or manually hit Ctrl+F

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I've tried:

pyautogui.hold(["ctrl"])
pyautogui.press("f")

Sure, Selenium might work, but I like using Vivaldi as my browser, and I want to figure out how to accomplish Ctrl+F with the current setup.

Comment: Try hotkeys

 `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Keyboard Control Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) documentation for that, using `pyautogui` functions.

In order to find something in the browser using the keys `CTRL` + `F` you can use the following commands:

```
import pyautogui

# You can define what you want to search
find = 'google'

# Use keys below
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')

# Write what you want
pyautogui.write(find, interval=0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'hotkey' function instead. It should look something like this:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
```